# scrartcl and fancyhdr: Strange spacing behaviour

Tags: spacing, header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr

Consider the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\thepage}{1}}{}{
                    \textbf{foo}\\
                    \textbf{bar}\\
                    \textbf{baz}
        }
}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

This is how pages 2 and 3 of the example look like:

[image]

as you can see the rows of *x* are not at the same height. Additionall *baz* does not start where *foo* and *bar* do - it is a bit more at the left.

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: You surely find, in the log file, a warning issued by `fancyhdr` about `\headheight`.

Comment: And the spaces after the opening braces and some of the closing braces matter Use `{%` to hide them.

Comment: @egreg please, could you write the answer?

Comment: The example code does not give the result of the images, because `\ ` does not result in a line break but only a inter word space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known and documented behavior of `fancyhdr`. If at the first usage of the defined header the package finds that the header is vertically bigger than `\headheight`, it will issue a message and change `\headheight` for the subsequent pages.

You will find the following message in your `.log` file:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (17.0pt):
 Make it at least 38.8842pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Thus you know that you need to set:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{39pt}
```

in your preamble (rounding is better):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\setlength{\headheight}{39pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\value{page}}{1}}%
    {}%
    {\bfseries
     \makebox[0pt][r]{\smash{\vrule height 1cm depth 2cm}}boo\\
     boo\\
     boo%
    }%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of changing `\headheight` I would recommend to use KOMA-Script option `headheight` or `headlines` so that `typearea` can take the large head into account while calculation of page areas. Also option `headinclude` could be useful with such a large head.

Answer (score 6):

Usage of `fancyhdr` with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. Nevertheless, if you switch to `scrlayer-scrpage` you will get a similar warning message, because the default height of the head is only one line. But KOMA-Script provides options `headheight` and `headlines` to setup the page with a larger head. In the example you are using three lines, so `headlines=3` should be a good choice:

```
\documentclass[headlines=3]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\manualmark
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}
\chead{\ifnum\value{page}=1\else foo\\bar\\baz\fi}

\begin{document}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you don't want the head elements being centered but a left aligned block that is centered, you may use, e.g., a `tabular` inside the head definition. And to remove the slanted font, set also the font element `pageheadfoot`:

```
\documentclass[headlines=3]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\manualmark
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}
\chead{\ifnum\value{page}=1\else \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}foo\\bar\\bazooka\end{tabular}\fi}

\begin{document}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

I would also suggest not to refer to the page number in the head but to use two different page styles:

```
\documentclass[headlines=3]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\manualmark
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\bfseries}
\chead{\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}foo\\bar\\bazooka\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\newpage
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]