# scrartcl and fancyhdr on first page

Tags: spacing, header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr

In relation to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141613/scrartcl-and-fancyhdr-strange-spacing-behaviour) question, I'd like to get a fancy header just on the first page of my `scrartcl` document (height about 150 pts), but even using `\thispagestyle{myfancyhdr}` all the following pages display a big blank empty header, without any picture, pushing the whole content downwards, although the main style is `plain` or `empty`.

I don't want it! Is there any way to avoid it?

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

[...]

\usepackage[...]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{ciccio}{%
%\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{
\includegraphics[width=3cm
]{strathlogo}
}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{ciccio}

[...]

\end{document}
```

Comment: When working with a class from »[KOMA-cript](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« you should better use its »scrpage-scrlayer« package (or the older »scrpage2«), but not »[fancyhdr](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)«.

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenDonig. Nevertheless, I’m not sure what is your actual problem. (Your MWE is neither minimal nor working.) You specify `\pagestyle{empty}` in the beginning. I would always put `\pagestyle` after `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and it seems you rather want `\pagestyle{ciccio}`, because `\thispagestyle{ciccio}` only applies to a single page. You’ll probably also want to add `\setlength{\headheight}{105pt}` to your preamble.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Or you need some more help?

Comment: Yes, everything's fine now! Sorry I still have to understand how the site works. I wanted to post a big THANKS to your reply! My assignment looks really cool now, the solution works perfectly, your example was so clear. Btw the 11 pts are going to be changed according to my lecturers' requests, that's why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `fancyhdr` works bad when using KOMA classes.

You should use `scrpage-scrlayer` (or the older `scrpage2`) instead of it.

Your `fancyhdr` code for defining the new style `ciccio` can be replaced by this one:

```
\deftriplepagestyle{ciccio}
    {}
    {}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{strathlogo}}
    {}
    {\pagemark}
    {}
```

In the following MWE I've added `height=1cm` just for displaying purposes, remove it in your document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\deftriplepagestyle{ciccio}
    {}
    {}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{strathlogo}} %remove the height option in your doc
    {}
    {\pagemark}
    {}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{ciccio}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If, with your image, you get a warning about `\headheight too low`, you'd better adjust the `\headheight` too.

Comment: Just a remark: The package option `11pt` could be left out, it’s the default for KOMA-Script.