# Modifying Koma-Script header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I'm trying to customize the header of my `srcartcl`. I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157285/scrartcl-and-fancyhdr-on-first-page) which lead me to use `\deftriplepagestyle` to include an image into my header. Neat!

```
\deftriplepagestyle{default}
{}
{}
{\includegraphics[height=0.6cm,valign=c]{myCoolLogo}-Software} 
{}
{\pagemark}
{}
```

However, I would also want to include the section name (and maybe number) into the header and I cannot find any solutions on the web, which allow both (section names and image).

(How) can this be done?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. It is simpler than you think. `\deftriplepagestyle` is far too complex for normal use.

Comment: I did. What I found was \automark{section}. But I do not see how I could pass an Image to automark and using \deftriplepagestyle together with automark Latex seems to ignore automark. Probably because it defines a completely new style which I then use, while automark changes the "default" style. Actually I called my style "default" in the hopes to overwrite this default style and still get the effect of automark.

Comment: Probably you don't even need an extra package, KOMA-script provides a lot of commands for running headings. Take an hour to read the sections in the manual. You get it with `texdoc scrguien` on the command line. »scrguien« is »scrguide in english«.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the interface for advanced users, use the simple interface for normal users.

```
\documentclass[
headheight=22pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\automark{section}
\ohead{\includegraphics[height=.6cm]{example-image-1x1}}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```